# greatest difference of any 3 given numbers-make code effective

Tags: python

I did this in vocareum lab for python but I did not get full points for the correctness and got full points for syntax. Any suggestions on how to make my code more efficient without using inbuilt python functions? Thanks a ton for your help.

Task: find the greatest difference of any given 3 numbers without using python functions like max, min, and sorted. Use if or while.

```
def greatest_difference(n1, n2, n3):
   d1=n1-n2
   d2=n1-n3
   d3=n2-n3

   diff1=abs(d1)
   diff2=abs(d2)
   diff3=abs(d3)

   if diff1>diff2 and diff1>diff3:
        return str(diff1) 
   elif diff2>diff1 and diff2>diff3:
        return str(diff2)
   elif diff3>diff1 and diff3>diff2:
        return str(diff3)
```

Comment: But `abs` is a built-in function. Is that allowed?

Comment: Why are you returning `str` instead of the actual difference as a number?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "review and suggest changes to my working code" is off topic, and better suited for Code Review site

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: The OP says they didn't get full points for correctness, but it's not clear to me what is incorrect (aside from possibly the conversion to `str`).

Comment: @ShadowRanger or perhaps the use of `abs`.

Comment: I got rid of the abs and the str in the return. I got better score. thanks

Comment: @ShadowRanger then you should probably vote it as "unclear what you're asking" and ask for more details. As it is, all we can do is speculate and rewrite it differently over and over again without any clear spec to decide what's right. If it doesn't work then it needs enough details of errors, expected behaviour, etc. to allow anyone to troubleshoot it. As is, I still think it's a "please review my code" question, which is fine, but not on topic.

Answer (score 0):

Just redefine the functions in a reasonable way.

```
def my_max(a, b):
    return a if a >= b else b
```

so you can do:

```
def greatest_difference(a, b, c):
    diffs = b-a, c-b, c-a

    # avoids the use of the `abs` built-in
    for i, diff in diffs:
        if diff < 0:
            diffs[i] = diff * (-1)

    d1, d2, d3 = diffs
    return my_max(d1, my_max(d2, d3))
```